# re-enable chrome roll-over tooltip inside "Sources" tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How to re-enable chrome developer tools roll-over inside "Sources" tab ?

(sentence or some result of function data)
It's suddenly stopped working inside my chrome dev tools.

[image]

Comment: If you mean the tooltip shown when hovering a variable/expression, it's a bug, fixed in the next version of Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, the tooltip .. so what do i spouse to do now? wait for the next update ?

Comment: Wait or use Chrome Canary for a month until the update is released.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! bty - is this known issue ?

Comment: https://crbug.com/1033022. Actually, the next update of 79 should include the fix so it'll be within this week, probably.